# Setup a Proxy for all http(s) calls in my computer

Tags: proxy

I want to setup a proxy in my computer (say 127.0.0.1:1234) so that ports 80 and 443 won't allow any application to connect to internet. If you want any app to connect to internet, they should be configured to use the proxy. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Thanks.